# no /run/dbus/system_bus_socket

Tags: upgrade, systemd, dbus

I wanted to upgrade from 17.10 to 18.04 but the upgrade failed, I think the reason was that *policykit-1* was left unconfigured.

Rebooting did not help and now I am in the emergency console. I found that I have a `/var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`, but not `/run/dbus/system_bus_socket`.

On another machine, I have `system_bus_socket` in both directories. Any idea what I can do to repair the system?

Answer (score 0):

The directory /var/run should be a link to /run (similarly for /var/lock is a link to /run/lock).  Check this with:

```
$ ls -ald /run /var/run /var/lock /run/lock
```

You should see something link this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 38 root root 1220 Jun 24 07:35 /run
drwxrwxrwt  5 root root  140 Jun 23 16:51 /run/lock
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    9 Oct 21  2011 /var/lock -> /run/lock
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root    4 Mar 22  2014 /var/run -> /run
```

If you do not, then this would point to the problem, but not why it is in this state.  See https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1859432 for a possible fix.